# MariaDB and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have been using elasticsearch with MySQL without any problems recently. My server was recently migrated over from MySQL to MariaDB and now the JDBC river just seems to freeze up with even the most basic syncs. Does anyone know if they are compatible?

Here is a sample code:

```
PUT /_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta
{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://HOST/DATABASE",
        "user": "username",
        "password": "password",
        "sql" : "select * from table"
    }
}
```

It just hangs on the following:

```
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,080][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wade Wilson] [_river] update_mapping [my_jdbc_river] (dynamic)
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,082][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.JDBCRiver] [Wade Wilson] [jdbc][my_jdbc_river] starting JDBC river: URL [jdbc:mysql://HOST/DATABASE], strategy [simple], index/type [jdbc/jdbc]
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,083][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth] waiting for cluster state YELLOW
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,083][INFO ][org.xbib.elasticsearch.river.jdbc.strategy.simple.SimpleRiverMouth] ... cluster state ok
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,094][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wade Wilson] [_river] update_mapping [my_jdbc_river] (dynamic)
[2014-05-19 16:11:49,113][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Wade Wilson] [_river] update_mapping [my_jdbc_river] (dynamic)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the jdbc-river is compatible with MariaDB, you have to ask [Jorg Prante](https://github.com/jprante)

Comment: Hi, @user2694306 , did you find the solution? Could you share it or accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Download MariaDB's "connector":

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-the-mariadb-java-client/

Comment: Consider adding more detail please.

Answer (score 0):

Download **mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar** at 
[https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-java/1.1/](http://mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar)

them move mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar into /your_path_to_elasticsearch/plugins like below:

```
> [root@SpaceConnection elasticsearch-1.3.4]# ll plugins/jdbc/
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 280826 Oct 16 22:03 elasticsearch-river-jdbc-1.3.4.0.jar
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    380 Oct 16 22:03 log4j2.xml
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    234 Oct 16 22:03 log4j.properties
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 230704 Mar 29  2014 mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar
```

then run bin/elasticsearch

```
[2014-10-16 23:34:41,712][INFO ][node                     ] [Apache Kid] version[1.3.4], pid[15632], build[a70f3cc/2014-09-30T09:07:17Z]
[2014-10-16 23:34:41,712][INFO ][node                     ] [Apache Kid] initializing ...
[2014-10-16 23:34:41,734][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Apache Kid] loaded [jdbc-1.3.4.0-e13884c], sites []
OpenJDK Server VM warning: You have loaded library /var/www/html/bibi.baonam/elasticsearch-1.3.4/lib/sigar/libsigar-x86-linux.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
[2014-10-16 23:34:45,060][INFO ][node                     ] [Apache Kid] initialized
[2014-10-16 23:34:45,060][INFO ][node                     ] [Apache Kid] starting ...
[2014-10-16 23:34:45,195][INFO ][transport                ] [Apache Kid] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/118.69.197.136:9300]}
[2014-10-16 23:34:45,225][INFO ][discovery                ] [Apache Kid] elasticsearch/rn5hDK2YTCKsC53RKt5MMg
[2014-10-16 23:34:48,244][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Apache Kid] new_master [Apache Kid][rn5hDK2YTCKsC53RKt5MMg][SpaceConnection][inet[/118.69.197.136:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-10-16 23:34:48,286][INFO ][http                     ] [Apache Kid] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/118.69.197.136:9200]}
[2014-10-16 23:34:48,288][INFO ][node                     ] [Apache Kid] started
[2014-10-16 23:34:49,087][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Apache Kid] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
```

Note at line 3: [2014-10-16 23:34:41,734][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Apache Kid] loaded [jdbc-1.3.4.0-e13884c], sites []

Of course, you must install step by step at https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc#how-to-start-the-jdbc-river before